# Disabling a getter in an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class Person {
   constructor(){}

   set name(){

   }

   // delete get name() {} 
}
```

Can you disable the getter for a property? Are there unintended consequences? Should I just throw? Return undefined?

Comment: There is no getter until you declare one in the first place? Just try it out: `(new Person).name`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your class as you've defined it there, there **is** no getter for `name`; trying to read `name` from an instance of `Person` will yield `undefined` (as though `name` weren't defined for the instance at all). This is defined by the [`OrdinaryGet` abstract operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryget) in the spec, which says that if a property is an accessor property but its `get` operation is `undefined`, the result of getting the property is `undefined`. (More on this below.)

If you want to make trying to read `name` an error, then yes, implement a getter and throw.

Examples of both:

```js
class NoError {
  set name(value){
  }
}
let n = new NoError();
console.log(n.name);

class HasError {
  get name() {
    throw new Error("'name' cannot be read");
  }
  set name(value){
  }
}
let h = new HasError();
console.log(h.name);
```

Here's a simpler example not using classes:

```js
var obj = {
  set name(value) {
  }
};
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true
console.log(obj.name);                   // undefined
```

Now you may be thinking "That's acting like the object doesn't have a `name` property, right?" But no, it isn't. The object has the property, it just has no getter.

If it were acting like it didn't have the property, the JavaScript engine would look at the prototype to find it, and we can see from the spec link above and from this example that it doesn't:

```js
var proto = {
  name: "Name on prototype"
};
var obj = Object.create(proto, {
  name: {
    set(value) {
    }
  }
});
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true
console.log(obj.name);                   // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer. I was, however, confusing a JSHint error with a javascript error. Would it be wiser to silence the warning or implement it with a throw?

Comment: @MathieuBertin: It's up to you. :-) If you want reading the property to throw, implement a getter that throws; if you want it to result in undefined, silence the warning/error.

Answer (score 0):

I would `throw` an exception in the getter to avoid unintentional incorrect use.